# Names are missing when decompiling DLL

Tags: .net

I have a DLL-file I'm not able to fully decomplie neither with .NET Reflector nor JetBrains dotPeek.

Basically all fields are missing their names like:

```
private int ;
private string ;
private bool ;
```

Is the dll obfuscated? Or could these names be generated on runtime?

Comment: interesting - did you also try ILSpy (Reflector clone)?

Comment: Just tried ILSpy, there the names are replaced with a gray box containing text like: STX, ETX, ENQ etc.

Comment: and final try - what happens when you decompile with ildasm? It looks like obfuscation, replacing the identifiers with garbled names. But on the other hand, private members *do not* have names in the output, I think Reflector names them int1, int2, ...

Comment: @Axarydax *locals* don't have names; "private members" sounds like "fields", and fields always have names. Those names could be illegal in C#, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for the clarification, it's too late in the evening

Comment: @Majako yes, it sounds like it is obfuscated. That *usually* strongly suggests it isn't "yours" to be poking around in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CLI standard, the one that says what characters are valid symbols, has *very* flexible rules.  Necessarily so, it describes a VM that many languages can target.  And the rules of what characters are valid in identifiers are a language implementation detail so making them too strict would have made it difficult to port such languages to the CLR.

Tools make use of this flexibility.  Both C# and VB.NET do, they generate weirdo names with characters like `$` and `<` to ensure that names that they auto-generate for things like iterators and lambda expressions will never collide with identifiers picked by the programmer.

And obfuscators take advantage of this.  Characters like STX and ENQ are ASCII control codes, codes with values less than 0x20.  With the advantage that many programs won't be able to display them at all since most fonts do not have a glyph for that character code.

You are almost certainly violating the license terms for this program.  A "do not reverse-engineer" clause is boilerplate in most any license.  A software vendor never goes through the trouble of obfuscating and then not include that clause.

Comment: There are more invisible characters if the obfuscator uses Unicode characters, as there are many more kinds of spaces, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Spaces

Comment: I don't know about that "A software vendor never goes through the trouble of obfuscating and then not include that clause."
Most malware doesn't come with a EULA.